# How do I identify Ad Distribution Network in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I have a case statement which produces [Default Channel Grouping channel definitions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en)

Does someone know how I can identify the column Ad Distribution Network (open Paid Serach in my link and you will see where that column is needed)?

Comment: You could try asking them to add it to the schema. Since the service was started I know at least 20 so columns were added, mostly because users were requesting it. Since it's a premium service you also have access to support. Go for it.

Comment: I will consider it. Thanks for the advice Pentium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all dimensions/metrics are available into BigQuery.  In this case, this dimension (Ad Distribution Network) is only available in Google Analytics because Google AdWords is linked to the Google Analytics view.  That link is not available to Google BigQuery.  This is why you don't see metrics like: impression, clicks, cpc in BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for.